# Storyboard in Xcode 8 is broken for more than 8 tabs

Tags: storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, xcode8

In previous versions of Xcode, when you had more than 8 tabs in a UITabBarController they would all be displayed in storyboard.  As you added more tabs they simply squished together, but they all fit on the screen.  This allowed for very easy drag and drop to reorder them.  With xCode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002) running on macOS Sierra Version 10.12.2, this is no longer the case.  It now shows a "More" tab just like the app will when it is running.

If you click on a tab to reorder it, it will grab the tab in the background.  It is impossible to grab a tab in the foreground to reorder them.  When you select them, you are selecting them in the blind and there are a bunch of blue lines displayed.

[image]
The only solution that I have found is to delete them all from the tab bar controller and reinsert them in the correct order...not an optimal solution.  To duplicate this, create at least 16 tabs so that each one displayed has another one "behind" it.

I submitted an Apple bug report...in November 2016 with a response that is no help.  They said the following: "Engineering has provided the following information regarding this issue: You can reorder tab bar items using the Document Outline area as a workaround."

The problem is that while you can select them this way, you can't reorder them.  I responded to Apple with this same observation, but have received no reply.

[image]

Has anyone else encountered this and found a solution?

Comment: My suggestion would be "don't do that". Configure the tab bar controller in code. You can leave the view controllers in the storyboard; just don't hook them up via relationships in the storyboard. (However, I would also contend that a tab bar controller with 21 children is a really bad idea, both from UX and memory perspective. I think you should rethink your architecture.)

Comment: I am not really worried about the UX aspect as this is an in-house app and each of the first seven tabs get around 95% of the use.   Since the others are used very infrequently, and are only one tab away, having the rest of them conveniently parked under "More" still makes sense to me. I guess I don't understand the memory concerns though.  I thought UIKit handled loads and unloads as necessary to handle the memory load, even with a tab bar.  Am I wrong on this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you think you mean by "unloaded". View controllers cannot be deallocated if they are all acting as the children of a parent simultaneously. So you are asking 21 view controllers and all their data and the state of their views to exist simultaneously. Of course if Instruments tells you all is well, then all is well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I did indeed have a misunderstanding of this.  The fact is I never had a memory crisis, but only because I was getting lucky.  I will indeed need to rethink the layout and design.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Yes, the way to test would be to run the app and work in _every single one_ of the tabs. Now see what's happened to the memory.

Comment: What I would suggest is a UINavigationController with a table view listing the names of the "tabs". Each "tab" would then be merely a pushed view controller, which is deallocated when you pop back to the table view to pick another "tab".

Comment: That is the same thing I was thinking.  It won't be pretty, but neither is this one :)

Comment: My ultimate solution to this was to write a slider navigation controller.  The underlying view is a uicollectionview with another view controller displayed on top of it.  Using swipe gestures I can slide the top view controller over to reveal the collection view below which contains large buttons for each possible view the app can display.  Selecting one of the buttons results in the top view controller switching and sliding back into position.  There are third party solutions for this, but writing my own from scratch didn't take very long and was really pretty satisfying.